# The initial value problem $y'=xy^{1/3}$ has more than one solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given initial condition $y(0)=0$, solve the initial value problem $$y'(x)=xy^{1/3}.$$

I know that it is not Lipschitz at $y=0$ and by solving I arrived at the solution 
$$y=({x^3}/{3\sqrt{3}}).$$
Now how can I conclude that it has more than one solution? Please explain.

Comment: How about the solution $y\equiv 0$?

Comment: I disagree with the other solution

Comment: You can check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274119/is-lipschitzs-condition-necessary-for-existence-of-unique-solution-of-an-i-v-p)

Comment: For every $x_0\geqslant0$, a solution is $$y(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 0&\text{if}&0\leqslant x\leqslant x_0\\ \left(\frac13(x^2-x_0^2)\right)^{3/2}&\text{if}&x\geqslant x_0\end{array}\right.$$ Extreme cases are $$y(x)=\frac{x^3}{3\sqrt{3}}$$ for every $x\geqslant0$, when $x_0=0$, and $$y(x)=0$$ for every $x\geqslant0$, when $x_0\to\infty$. Note that the function in the question is not a solution.

Comment: When can we say that an IVP has a unique solution? I mean if it satisfies the Picard's theorem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you have the solution $y(x)=0$, as frog suggested. Moreover, by separating variables, it seems to me the solution you get is
\begin{equation}
y(x)=\frac{1}{3\sqrt3}x^3,
\end{equation}
which again satisfies your initial datum.