# Find more solutions to the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP,
$$x'(t)=f(t,x(t))=x^{2/3},\quad x(1)=0$$
Find 3 solutions to the IVP with domain $[-1,1]$

I separated the variables and solved the ODE, got as a solution
$$x(t)=0,~x(t)=\frac{t^3-3t^2+3t-1}{27}$$
How do I find a 3rd solution?
$x(t)=0$ solves the IVP trivially. I still need a third solution though.

Comment: i have found the same solution as you

Comment: Try to consider $x(t) = \left(\frac{t-c}{3}\right)^3$ for $-1< t < c$ and $x(t) = 0$ for $c < t < 1$.

Comment: I would say that there are infinitely many solutions, but maybe the piecewise-defined functions count as one.

Comment: You can find a similar question here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015610/numer-of-solutions-for-ivp?rq=1